# WPF MVVM: Top panel to block all controls

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, rectangles

My main window **view**:

```
<Window.Resources>
       <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibility"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="TopGrid">
    <Rectangle x:Name="TopPanel" Grid.ZIndex="3" 
               Fill="LightBlue"  Opacity="0.3" 
               Visibility="{Binding IsContentBlocked, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" />
    <Grid Name="main"  DataContext="{StaticResource mainViewModel}">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1.2*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Here my controls: stackpanel, buttons, groupboxes, etc. -->
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**View model**:

```
    private bool isContentBlocked = false;        

    public bool IsContentBlocked
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isContentBlocked;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.isContentBlocked == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            this.isContentBlocked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsContentBlocked");
        }
    }
```

Initially when I launch WPF app, top panel should be hidden so all content shoudl be enabled, user should be able to play with them but for some reason, the top panel is not being hidden, it is shown, so all content cannot be accessed. I use a rectangle to make content to figure as blocked.

What am I doing wrong?

My view model is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged correctly.

Comment: This `DataContext="{StaticResource mainViewModel}"` suggests that you don't have your viewmodel available upper the tree, so your `Rectangle.Visibility` has nothing to bind to. You should check "output" window during debugging to see binding failures.

Comment: One thing jumps out: you should not be using a `TwoWay` binding mode on `Visibility`.

Comment: @Evk thanks for the suggestion. I had to move up the datacontext to the outer grid. now works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Provided that your `IsContentBlocked` property is defined in `mainViewModel`, you should set the `DataContext` of the `TopGrid` to this one

```
<Grid x:Name="TopGrid" DataContext="{StaticResource mainViewModel}">
    <Rectangle x:Name="TopPanel" Grid.ZIndex="3" 
               Fill="LightBlue"  Opacity="0.3" 
               Visibility="{Binding IsContentBlocked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" />
    <Grid Name="main">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1.2*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Here my controls: stackpanel, buttons, groupboxes, etc. -->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: yes, moving datacontext to outer grid is working. Thx.